# why this setState is unexpectedly passing the old value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-state

I've this parent component(`Parent`) which holds an inner component(`InnerComp`) (for organizing code). The inner component has another nested component(`Comp`) which I'm importing from another file. to update `Parent`'s state from `Comp`, I'm passing the `setParentCount` function via prop in `Comp`

```js
function Parent() {
  const [parentCount, setParentCount] = useState(0);

  const InnerComp = () => (
    <>
      <h2>necessary inner comp</h2>
      <hr />
      <Comp setParentCount={setParentCount} />
    </>
  );

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Parent</h1>
      <hr />
      <InnerComp />
      <p>parent comp count = {parentCount}</p>
    </>
  );
}
```

`Comp` has its own state as well. the "Click" button in `Comp` calls the `handleClick` function on click. the `handleClick` function is trying to update both the `Comp` and `Parent`'s state. but it seems that `compCount` is not getting updated.

```js
function Comp({ setParentCount }) {
  const [compCount, setCompCount] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(compCount);
  }, [compCount]);

  function handleClick() {
    setCompCount((prev) => prev + 1);

    setParentCount((prev) => prev + 1);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <h3>child comp</h3>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Click</button>
      <p>child comp count = {compCount}</p>
    </>
  );
}
```

I've added the `useEffect` as well for `compCount` in `Comp`. it's logging every time I click the button. but the same initial value. means the `setCompCount` function is setting the old value every time. I wonder why it is happening.

When I add the `InnerComp`'s JSX directly inside `Parent` instead of making a new inner component, it works fine. But I kinda need the `InnerComp` to keep my code organized.

I know I can make it work with `useContext`, but I think having context here will make this tiny component really heavy.

[Here](https://rhsju1.csb.app/)'s a codesandbox

Comment: I suggest looking at ["Different components at the same positions reset state"](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/preserving-and-resetting-state#different-components-at-the-same-position-reset-state) heading from Reacts beta documentation. The **pitfall** section under that heading explains your scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `InnerComp` is getting renewed everytime the parent state updates. Updating the parent state triggers rerender of the parent component in which `InnerComp` is declared and rendered. That causes `InnerComp` and also `Comp` which is in `InnerComp` to be initialized everytime the parent state change. It is not a good way to declare a component inside a compoent.

[React Docs suggestion](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/your-first-component#nesting-and-organizing-components) on nested component defination.

To resolve this, you can move `InnerComp` component declaration outside of the `Parent` and pass the necessary props. If you don't like passing the `setParentCount` props multiple times to child component you can consider using react context or state management libraries such as Redux, Recoil, etc.

```
const InnerComp = ({setParentCount}) => (
    <>
      <h2>necessary inner comp</h2>
      <hr />
      <Comp setParentCount={setParentCount} />
    </>
 );

function Parent() {
  const [parentCount, setParentCount] = useState(0);

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Parent</h1>
      <hr />
      <InnerComp setParentCount={setParentCount} />
      <p>parent comp count = {parentCount}</p>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your issue is that you are defining `InnerComp` within the `Parent` component. This means that every time your `Parent` component rerenders, it redefines the `InnerComp` function, creating a new component type each time. In other words, on every rerender of `Parent`, `InnerComp` represents a completely new component, and using it will replace the previous version of `InnerComp` and start with the default state.

To fix this, you should move the definition of `InnerComp` outside the `Parent` component, and make any dependencies of `Parent` passed in as props to `InnerComp` like so:

```
const InnerComp = ({ setParentCount }) => (
  <>
    <h2>necessary inner comp</h2>
    <hr />
    <Comp setParentCount={setParentCount} />
  </>
);

function Parent() {
  const [parentCount, setParentCount] = useState(0);
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Parent</h1>
      <hr />
      <InnerComp setParentCount={setParentCount} />
      <p>parent comp count = {parentCount}</p>
    </>
  );
}
```

This way, `InnerComp` doesn't keep getting redefined and represents the same component type each rerender, thus preserving its internal state.

Here's a [CodeSanbox with a working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-forest-qjfbzj?file=/test/parent.js).